# What does the colon part means in Apache error.log's [client] block on Debian?

Tags: debian, apache-2.4, log-files

I am trying to debug an issue with Apache 2.4 on Debian 8 (jessie). I notice lines like the following in my `/var/log/apache2/error.log`:

```
[Sun May 15 11:53:10.526964 2016] [authz_core:error] [pid 14805] [client 32.135.203.150:43595] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/admin/
```

Question: in `[client]` block, what does the part `:43595` means? I would guess it's a port number, but I am not sure since it doesn't appear in [Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html#errorlog) and it's not described in `/usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian.gz` either. I also tried to find if the log format isn't customized somewhere, but `grep -rnw '/etc/apache2/' -e 'ErrorLogFormat'` returns nothing.

Comment: That's standard notation for `IPv4:Port` it is not limited to Apache httpd. Also it's a colon not a semi-colon.

Comment: Sorry about mixing the two! I know it's standard, but it doesnt appear in documentation for some reason and isn't described in file that tells differences between vanilla and Debian versions of Apache. I thought it may have other meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is the standard notation for port numbers when describing TCP / UDP connection endpoints.

Comment: Then why it doesn't appear in documentation example? Do you know if it's configured separately?

Comment: The Apache in Debian could be a customized version that includes the port number by default in the logs. This is just an educated guess though.